how to make background of image match color of page in flutter
this is the image from figma
enter image description here
enter image description here
here in the above screen how to remove the white background
enter image description here
this is my code
i tried changing the color of asset , which changes the color of whole image  , also tried using boxfit .  i want to achieve the page as in figma design .

Flutter does not have the function to independently modify the color of a certain area of the image. You can only let the UI modify it, or use PS to fill it.

If the image is from figma and it doesn't showing path when you hover it, the image is in  pixel format and the white background cannot be removed, otherwise if it show the blue path when you hover, the shape is in vector format and you can export it without the white background by selecting the shape and export as png to preserve the background transparency

To replace the color white in your image, you can utilize the ColorFiltered widget in Flutter. Wrap your Image.asset(...) widget within the ColorFiltered widget, specifying the desired background color and blend mode as follows:
...
child: ColorFiltered(
  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
    _yourBackgroundColor,
    BlendMode.srcATop,
  ),
  child: Image.asset(...),
),
...

In this setup, BlendMode.srcATop is used to composite the source over the destination image, specifically where they overlap. As white is the color you wish to replace, this blend mode effectively achieves that.
